# How can I receive specific fields from a SQL query?

Tags: sql

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`state` = 'active' ORDER BY updated_at DESC;
```

I only want the fields first_name, last_name, and email.
How can I create a query that only gives me this information?

Comment: `SELECT first_name, last_name,email FROM users..`

Comment: How can you know how to use SQL and not know how to do this? I can't believe that every SQL tutorial uses only `SELECT *`, or even that most of them do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*` means all fields, to get individual fields just list individual fields in a comma separated list.

```
SELECT `users`.first_name, `users`.last_name, `users`.email
FROM `users` 
WHERE `users`.`state` = 'active' ORDER BY updated_at DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, email FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`state` = 'active' ORDER BY updated_at DESC;
```